# Ring of formal Laurent series: units and defining operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm struggling to see how one could show that the ring of formal Laurent series in $F$ is unital.

I defined addition and multiplication to be, for $p, q \in F((t))$: if $$p = \sum_{i \in X} a_i t^i$$ for some finite set $X \subset \mathbb{Z}$ and likewise for $Y$ in $$q = \sum_{j \in Y} b_j t^j$$ then

$$p+q = \sum_{k \in X \cup Y}(a_k + b_k)t^k$$

and

$$pq = \sum_{l \in X + Y} \sum_{i+j=l} a_i b_j t^l$$

where $X+Y = \{x+y\mid x \in X, y \in Y\}$ and $i \in X$, $j \in Y$.

I seem to have proved all of the necessary ring axioms save for the distributive property (not yet), but I can't figure out how to find units for this ring.  The units of the formal power series are defined as the elements such that $a_0$ is an unit in $F$ (and the other coefficients are defined recursively.  However, of course, $0$ may not be even in $X \cup Y$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Laurent series and Laurent polynomials

Actually, by using finite $X$ and $Y$, what you've written is only a definition for [Laurent *polynomial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) arithmetic, and not Laurent *series* arithmetic.

The expression you gave carry over directly, but the condition on $X$ and $Y$ is that they *have a least element*. Notice that if both have a least element, then so do $X\cup Y$ and $X+Y$.

### Now for your question

The expression $p = \sum_{i \in X} a_i t^i$ is one way to express $p$, but it's not the only way to write $p$.

If $0\notin X$, then notice that it can be added in for free:

$$p = \sum_{i \in X} a_i t^i=0t^0+\sum_{i \in X} a_i t^i=\sum_{i \in X'} a_i t^i$$ where $X'=X\cup\{0\}$. You can see that $X'$ still has a least element, which is either the least element of $X$ or $0$ itself. Naturally $a_0=0$ in this case. In other cases, you already have $a_0\neq 0$ given to you.

So actually you can see that every coefficient in a Laurent series is defined, it's just that there are limitations that make many of the coefficients $0$, and hence omissible. Such conditions are necessary because they ensure that each coefficient of the sum and product can be obtained from computations with *finitely* many nonzero numbers.

### Identity

I'd like to adapt the notation above so it's a little easier to write things. When I wrote $p_0$, I mean the coefficient of $0$ in $p$. Similarly $q_5$ is the $5$ coefficient of $q$. And $(pq)_{-1}$ is the $-1$ coefficient of the product $pq$.

Using this notation, your arithmetic formulas change into:

$$(p+q)_k = p_k + q_k\\
(p\cdot q)_k = \sum_{i+j=k} p_i q_j$$

The identity is the obvious candidate: the coefficent of $t^0$ should be $1$, and all other coefficients should be $0$. I'm going to call that particular series "$1$".

Checking the multiplication:

$$(p\cdot 1)_k = \sum_{i+j=k} p_i 1_j=p_k$$ (Can you see how that works?) This means that $p\cdot 1=p$, since all of their coefficients match. Thus $1$ is the identity.

### Units of $F[[t]]$

The units are not *defined* as you described. What you wrote was more like a description of the units of $F[[t]]$ (but not a definition.) Let's make that clear here.

To find all the units for the ring of power series over a ring $F$, I'm going to first have you look at units in the power series ring $F[[t]]$, which as you know looks just like $F((t))$ except coefficients below $0$ are always $0$.

First, let's look at units in $F[[x]]$. By definition, $p$ is a unit if there is a $q$ such that $p\cdot q=1$. Suppose $pq=1$. Then the formula for multiplication says that $p_0q_0=1\in F$, so we know for sure that $p_0$ has to be a unit.

Convesely, consider what $q$ must look like to invert $p$ if $p_0$ is a unit in $F$.

We have: $(p\cdot q)_0=p_0q_0=1$ and solving for $q_0$ we get $q_0=p_0^{-1}$. This is possible to write since $p_0$ is a unit of $F$.

Next $(p\cdot q)_1=p_1q_0+p_0q_1=0$, and solving for $q_1$ we get $q_1=-p_1q_0p_0^{-1}$

Next $(p\cdot q)_2=p_2q_0+p_1q_1+p_0q_2=0$, and solving for $q_2$ we get $q_2=-p_0^{-1}(p_2q_0+p_1q_1)$.

Continuing inductively, we produce an infinite series of $q_i$ with the property that their Laurent series $q$ satisfies $p\cdot q=1$. We have now established that units of $F[[t]]$ are exactly the series with a unit of $F$ in first coefficient.

### Units of $F((t))$

*(Note: as observed in the comments and other solution, this is insufficient when $F$ is not a domain. When the coefficient ring has zero divisors, there can be "more" units than this analysis expects.  It should be fine for at least domains, and in particular, $F$ a field.)*

<s>Finally, we tackle your unit question. First, notice that $t$ is a unit in this ring since it contains the series $t^{-1}$ which is $1$ in the $-1$ spot and $0$ elsewhere. Multiplying you'll find that $t\cdot t^{-1}=1$.</s>

Now let $p$ be any nonzero Laurent series. Obviously $p=t^{z}p'$ where $p'$ is a power series with a nonzero first coefficient. Since $t^z$ is obviously a unit, $p$ is a unit of $F((t))$ iff $p'$ is a unit of $F[[t]]$, but we already know that means that the lowest nonzero coefficient of $p'$ is a unit of $F$.

So there you have it: the units of $F((t))$ are the ones with lowest nonzero coefficient a unit of $F$. If $F$ is a field, then actually $F((t))$ is a field too. It turns out to be the ring of fractions of $F[[t]]$, in that case.

Comment: I was thinking that by saying $X$ was finite would be the same thing as (implicitly) saying it had a least element, but I'll make sure to add that extra assumption, thanks.

How should I go about finding units?

Comment: @Lost I added a bunch of information which hopefully gets you on track. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helps out.  When I looked around for about the units, I couldn't find anything that didn't look convoluted.

The fact that $F((t))$ is the ring of fractions of $F[[t]]$ is what I'll be proving right afterward.

Comment: I hadn't thought about $p = t^zp'$, I tried defining $p^{-1}$ to be the series for which the indices belonged to $-X$, the set consisting of the additive inverses of $X$ and you know how well that turned out.

Comment: @Lost I don't think I would call $F((t))$ a ring of fractions for general rings $F$, though. When $F$ is a field, it is safe to call it that, though.

Comment: Ah yes, $F$ is a field here.

Comment: @rschwieb: the second part of the statement "$p$ is a unit of $F((T))$ iff $p'$ is a unit of $F[[t]]$" needs some justification. Certainly, at first we only get from $p=t^zp'$ that the power series $p'$ is a unit of $F((t))$. But why is it immediately clear that $p'$ then must be a unit in $F[[t]]$ too?

Answer (score 5):

I am late to the game, but after some reflection upon my remark to rschwieb's answer, I came to the conclusion that his answer is in general incorrect when $F$ is not an integral domain. Here is an explicit counter-example:

Let $F:=\mathbb{C}[X]/(X^2)$ and let $\varepsilon$ be the image of $X$ in $F$, i.e. $F=\mathbb{C}[\varepsilon]$ with $\varepsilon^2=0$. Consider
$$
f(t):=\frac{\varepsilon}{t^2}-\frac{i}{t}\in F[t,1/t]\subseteq F((t))
$$
and
$$
g(t):=\varepsilon+it\in F[t]\subseteq F[[t]]
$$
Then $f(t)g(t)=1$ showing that the lowest non-zero coefficient (of $f$) need not be a unit in $F$.

<s>The cool thing about this example is that it is minimal in that it uses non-trivial nilpotent element of lowest possible order, which in turn - turns out - precludes constructing a $f$ with lowest degree $(-1)$, so the term $t^{-2}$ is actually necessary, *and* requires a pair of numbers that are inverse to each other with respect to both addition and multiplication, which forces introducing a $\sqrt{-1}$.</s>

**EDIT:** As pointed out by user **math54321** in the comments, the existence of $\sqrt{-1}$ is not necessary to realize a non-trivial example of minimal degree.

Comment: Hi, I somehow missed your comment 5 years ago. Today someone upvoted and I was drawn to take another look. Thanks for the careful reading. I've added a note along the lines of the problem you've brought forward.  +1

Comment: There's no need to introduce $\sqrt{-1}$: if $R$ is any non-reduced ring, then there exists $0 \ne a \in R$ with $a^2 = 0$, and taking $f := a + t, g := -\frac{a}{t^2} + \frac{1}{t} \in R((t))$ gives $fg = 1$

Comment: @math54321: Oh, you are completely right! I must have missed that case. Of course one "conjugate" the nilpotent element instead! Thanks for noticing and for correcting me!